# Загрузка массива JSON

Tags: jquery, json, javascript

Добрый день. Работаю с передачей JSON массивом. Не получается. Есть такой код подргружающий данные из файла data2.json:

```
 $.getJSON( "data2.json", function( json ) 
    {
      console.log( "JSON Data: " + json);
    });
```

И файл data2.json:

```
[
                    ['Shanghai', 23.7],
                    ['Lagos', 16,1],
                    ['Instanbul', 14.2]
]
```

**При выводе страницы в браузере в консоли выдаются ошибки:**
*No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.*

**И ошибка** *XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/%D0%A1%D0%90%D0%99%D0%A2%D0%AB/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8/highcharts/column-rotated-labels/data2.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access*

Версия JQuery 1.8.2. Что я не так сделал для вывода данных массива JSON? Подскажите с массивами JSON не работал ни разу.

Comment: По умолчанию получение данных с серверов, отличных от текущего, запрещено. Для разрешения такого обмена требуется прописать тот самый упомянутый заголовок (естественно, файловая система сама его не отдаст), можете почитать про [CORS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), если интересно. Почему не все локальные файлы считаются за один сервер - не могу сказать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что проблема в том, что вы тестируете не на web-сервре, на просто на диске С.
Скорее всего браузер не может определить имя хоста (домена) и ругается на ваш код.

Comment: Да верно. Я поместил на веб-сервер и ошибки пропали, но все равно вывода массива JSON нету. Как вывести к примеру корректно в alert или   console или в блок html массив?

Comment: @IntegralAL, что такое html-массив? Простые объекты кидаются в консоль просто аргументом:

    console.log(obj, 'string', 12); // и все ок

Comment: потому что у вас в файле data2.json не json data
вот пример json:
{"success":true,"result":[{"category":"KAMERAS","products":[{"product_id":"42","product_name":"Canon 1D MK I","product_url":"Canon_1D_MK_I","image":"a16ed3a7a71cd637f3d052b2cbf1ba11.jpg","subcat_url":"Canon_Cameras","subcat_name":"KAMERAS","prod
.........

Comment: @Victor Halauko, вообще-то там единственная ошибка в апострофах вместо кавычек (ну и запятая в одном месте наверянка стоит вместо точки).

Comment: @Fike, Если ошибка в апострофах вместо кавычек, то это уже не json данные. Или я не прав?
Во вторых json данные начинаются с "{"

Comment: @Victor Halauko, вот я про то, что в JSON не обязательно объект сидит. `"string"` - это тоже валидная JSON-строка.

Comment: Решил модифицировать задачу вместо файла data2.json подключаю data.php содержащий:

    <?
    header("content-type: application/json"); 
    $array = array('Shanghai'=>23.7,
                   'Lagos'=>16,1,
          'Instanbul'=>14.2
          );
    echo json_encode($array); 
    ?>

Если запускать этот файл, то на экран выводится такая структура:

    {"Shanghai":23.7,"Lagos":16,"0":1,"Instanbul":14.2}

Хотя мне нужна такая структура данных:

    [['Shanghai', 23.7],['Lagos', 16,1],['Instanbul', 14.2]]

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: {"Shanghai":23.7,"Lagos":16,"0":1,"Instanbul":14.2} Вот это и есть json @Fike, посмотри в чем разница

Comment: @IntegralAL, ну соответственно так же разбивать на массивы

    $data = array(
        array('Shangai', 23.7),
        ...
    );

@Victor Halauko и что? `[]` - это тоже JSON, просто пустой массив. Я говорю, корневым элементом не обязательно является объект.

Comment: Мне не очень наравиться как вы подготовили данные.
Я обычно подготавливаю данные так:

   $array = array(
   
   "success"=>TRUE,// - (означает, что скрипт отработал без ошибок)
   
   'data'=>array(
   
   array('city'=>'Shangai', 'km'=>'23.7'),
   
   array('city'=>'Brest', 'km'=>'26.7')
   
   );
   );

echo json_encode($array); 

А потом вот так:


            if (data.success == true) {
   
    var num = json.data.length;
   
   if (num > 0) {
   
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    
    console.log(json.data[i].city +" - "+json.data[i].km+"km");
    
    }
   }
   
   
   }

Comment: Просто такой код легче через время дебажить. Вот например я, как другой разработчик не понял что такое 'Shanghai', 23.7. что означает эта цифра?
В моем случае это очевидно, что это расстояние и что Shanghai -> это город, а не имя категории.
@Fike, я не уверен, но мне кажется, что JSON это объект, который может содержать массивы. Об этом говорят "{}".  
JavaScript Object Notation – представление объектов JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

[[@Victor Halauko](/users/15514/victor-halauko)](/users/15514/victor-halauko)

> Об этом говорят "{}".

Ни о чем они не говорят. Спека JSON:

> A JSON text is a serialized object **or array**.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt

Видимо подразумевается, что остальные типы данных не имеет смысла сериализовать; в любом случае, большинство парсеров свободно десериализуют просто строку или число.

Comment: JSON  - JavaScript Object Notation

Comment: В яваскрипте практически любой тип данных является объектом. Но я уже спеку привелЮ я не знаю, какие еще доказательства нужны.

Comment: Ты прав:
This is a JSON array containing two objects:

   [
      {
         "precision": "zip",
         "Latitude":  37.7668,
         "Longitude": -122.3959,
         "Address":   "",
         "City":      "SAN FRANCISCO",
         "State":     "CA",
         "Zip":       "94107",
         "Country":   "US"
      },
      {
         "precision": "zip",
         "Latitude":  37.371991,
         "Longitude": -122.026020,
         "Address":   "",
         "City":      "SUNNYVALE",
         "State":     "CA",
         "Zip":       "94085",
         "Country":   "US"
      }
   ]